# jQuery DataTables server side mode not loading table rows

Tags: datatables

I'm using the DataTables javascript library (v1.13.1) and trying to get a basic server-side example up and running, but there's just no rows appearing in the table, only the headers. I have to tell DataTables the location in my server response where my array of objects is using the `ajax.dataSrc` option. I'm logging my servers JSON response to the console and it looks correct to me (I am including the required response values e.g. `draw`).

I've been pouring over the docs and looking at the official examples, but I just can't see what I'm doing wrong. There's no console errors, just no results in the table. Am I missing some required options?

Server Response:

```
{
    "draw": 1,
    "recordsFiltered": 13,
    "recordsTotal": 13,
    "watchlist": [
        {
            "added": 1610556680,
            ​​​​"status": 1151,
            "type": 2,
​            "name": "Blah"
        },
        ...and 12 more with same exact format
    ]
}
```

HTML:

```
<table id="my-datatable" class="stripe hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Added</th>
            <th>Type</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

Script:

```
var ajaxOpts = {
    url: '/MyEndpoint',
    success: function(data) {
        console.log('success', data); // looks fine
        $('#my-spinner').fadeOut(200);
    },
    error: function() {
        alert('Ajax Error...');
    },
    dataSrc: function(data) {
        console.log('dataSrc', data); // never called
        return JSON.parse(data).watchlist;
    },
    // dataSrc: 'watchlist', // also doesn't work
};

$('#my-datatable').DataTable({
    serverSide: true,
    ajax: ajaxOpts,
    pageLength: 50,
    columns: [
        { data: 'added' },
        { data: 'type' },
        { data: 'status' },
        { data: 'name' },
    ],
});
```

Comment: Thanks @andrewJames that was the solution for me. If you put it into an answer I'll accept it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Some notes:

(1) Don't use `success` in the DataTables Ajax configuration - this is used by DataTables and should not be used by you.

(2) You were correct to use `dataSrc: 'watchlist'`, since that is where your array of objects is located in your JSON. But it won't work until you fix point (1).

See the [`ajax.dataSrc`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.dataSrc) documentation for notes about not using `success`:

> the `success` option of `ajax` should not be altered - DataTables uses it internally to execute the table draw when the data load is complete.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use success and try this:

```
    ...
    dataSrc: function (json) {
        $('#my-spinner').fadeOut(200)
        return json.watchlist
    },
    ...
```